# Filter text and insert text after cursor or in register?

Tags: visual-mode, external-command

I want to filter some text through an external command without replacing the text, but rather have some way of inserting it afterwards or wherever I want.

Say I want to calculate:

```
2^8 =
```

I mark `2^8` in visual mode and type `:! bc`, this replaces `2^8` with `256`. However, I would rather just insert the result of the command after the `=` sign. Is this possible?

Comment: As a useful side-note to the answers below, if I wanted to filter part of the line to the `bc` command I could use the `vis` plugin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196826/how-to-filter-visual-selection), and select the relevant part of the line with V, then enter `:B ! bc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
2^8 =
1+1 = 3
2+4 =
4%8 =
```

this:

```
:g/=$/ t. | s/=// | exe '.!bc'  | -j
```

produces:

```
2^8 = 256
1+1 = 3
2+4 = 6
4%8 = 4
```

It finds each line ending in `=`, copies it below, trims off the `=`,
filters it through `bc`, then joins it to the line above.

*Notes*

- `:h :global` -- short form: `:g` -- executes the following commands on each line that matches.
- `:h :copy` -- short synomym: `:t` -- copy a range of lines elsewhere.
- `:h :substitute` -- short form: `:s` -- search and replace.
- `:h :execute` -- short form: `:exe` -- execute a string as a command, used here to allow another following command since otherwise `|` would be passed to the shell.
- `:h range!` -- filter a range of lines through an external program.
- `:h :join` -- short form: `:j` -- join a range of lines.

Comment: I did not realize that `: ! command` works on the whole line and not just on the selection, this explains why things didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
:%s/\(.*\)=\s*\zs$/\=system('bc -q <(echo '.shellescape(submatch(1)) . ')')/
```

This replaces line-endings terminated with `=` by `bc -q <(echo "expression")`.

See

- [`:h :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3asubstitute)
- [`:h sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub%2dreplace%2dspecial)
- [`:h /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs)
- [`:h system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29)
- [`:h shellescape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29)